# Selecting elements on "shift + arrow up"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some list of elements (each element is one line of text). When you click on it it changes color. After you clicked on some item if you press "shift + arrow up" above items are selected too. How to implement it? I thought it could go this way: put focus on particular element in ng-click function, and then in ng-keydown function implement selecting other elements. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in listCtrl.availableElements" class="list-elem" ng-class="{ 'selected' : listCtrl.availableElements[$index].selected }" ng-click="listCtrl.listHandler($event, listCtrl.availableElements[$index])" ng-keydown="$event.shiftKey && ($event.which == 38 || $event.which == 40) && listCtrl.listHandler($event, listCtrl.availableElements[$index])">
    <div>
        {{elem.text}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YV2844Ub0kQbo3g0nO6P?p=preview)

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div tabindex="{{$index}}" ng-keydown="moveCursor($event)" ng-repeat="elem in elements" ng-click="setCursor($index)">
    <span ng-class="{ 'selected' : elements[$index].selected }">{{$index}} : {{elem.text}}</span>
</div>
```

`tabindex` need to be added to allow the focus on the element.

On the `ng-click` i just set a cursor.

```
$scope.setCursor = function(index){
  var wasSelected = $scope.elements[index].selected;
  $scope.unselectAll();
  $scope.elements[index].selected = !wasSelected;
  $scope.cursor = index;
  $scope.initialCursor = index;
}
```

This cursor will be my pivot to selected the other elements. I need to save the `initialCursor` to know how to behave when selecting downward or upward.

On the `ng-keydown` i just handle the event myself and put some locks.

```
$scope.moveCursor = function(event){
  if(event.shiftKey && event.which == 38){
    if($scope.cursor > 0){
      $scope.selectUp();
    }
  }else if(event.shiftKey && event.which == 40){
    if($scope.cursor < $scope.elements.length-1){
      $scope.selectDown();
    }
  } 
}
```

The `selectUp()` and `selectDown()` are pretty similar :

```
$scope.selectDown = function(){
  //If the current cursor is ahead of the first click
   if($scope.cursor < $scope.initialCursor){
      $scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected = !$scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected;
      $scope.cursor += 1;
   }else{
      $scope.cursor += 1;
      $scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected = !$scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected;
   }
}

$scope.selectUp = function(){
    //If the current cursor is behind the first click
   if($scope.cursor > $scope.initialCursor){
      $scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected = !$scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected;
      $scope.cursor -= 1;
   }else{
      $scope.cursor -= 1;
      $scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected = !$scope.elements[$scope.cursor].selected;
   }
}
```

Lets have a look to the `selectUp` function.

I have two behavior to implements.

If i am ahead of the initial click and i `selectUp` i need to select the next item upward.

If i am behind the initial click and i `selectUp` i need to unselect the last item selected.

Hope it helped.

If you don't like my implementation, you can just use the "tabindex" tip to build your own.

Comment: btw, i scoped way too much vars, just use 'var =' if you don't need the function/variable in your view.

Comment: @bambi did you try my solution ?